# how to display a list in 3 columns

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I am displaying using `*ngFor` vertically.
I need to display this list on 3 columns;

I have tried to use `d-flex flex-wrap` but this didn't solve the problem. Also I set a fixed width for the div but this gave me a scrolling list.

Here is my code

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap container">
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.value" />
       <label> {{item.name}} </label>
    </li>
</div>
```

also I have tried to use ngFor on a div, thinking flex-wrap only works on divs but it gave me the same result

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list">
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.value" />
       <label> {{item.name}} </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using the CSS framework. Could you provide its name?

Comment: i am using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 3 columns with bootstrap it's class col-4 you need (12 bootstrap columns / 3) on your div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list" class="col-4">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.value" />
        <label> {{item.name}} </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `row` to wrap DOM and `col-3` to each `div` inside the wrap

AS below:

```
<div class="container row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list" class="col-3">
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.value" />
       <label> {{item.name}} </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-eg-ta9jgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: tell me for more help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list" class="col-3">
       <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.value" />
       <label> {{item.name}} </label>
    </div>
</div>
```